# The scroll bar and stretched to the height of the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need the scroll bar to appear in the first div if its contents are higher than the screen size. And the second div was stretched along the height of the screen.

How can I add a scrollbar to the first div?
`overflow: scroll;` does not work.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container-fluid{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid d-flex">
  <div class="row flex-fill">
    <div class="col-6" style="overflow: scroll;">
<form>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">1</th>
      <th scope="col">2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-success">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for the scroll to work, you need to limit the div to a fixed height, or at least some height that will be less than the height of the content inside this div.
For exampel:

```html
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid d-flex">
  <div class="row flex-fill" style="height: 200px;">
    <div class="col-6" style="overflow: scroll;height: 100%;">
<form>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">1</th>
      <th scope="col">2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-success">
    </div>
  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div></body>
```

Or, in some other way, indicate the height of the block in which the scroll should be turned on.

Comment: But I need a height equal to the height of the whole page, not 200 pixels.

Comment: Share the link to this project or to the code of the whole page so that I can see how this element looks on the page